# theme_hook_suggestions for string wildcard

Tags: theming

I need to create a copy of page.tpl.php using page--fixed_arg_0__variable_string_arg_1__fixed_arg_2.tpl.php as pattern. For example, if the URL is http://example.com/models/model-title/special-offers, *model-title* is the variable. I only want one template file instead of 10 or more.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! It's not clear what you are asking, especially because you say you want one template file instead of 10. if page.tpl.php is not enough, you should explain the pattern of the URLs to which you want to apply the same template file.

Answer (score 1):

What you'd need to do use the theme suggestions. So you'd have 1 template file e.g. page--fixed.tpl.php

Then in template.php you could have an if statement e.g.:

```
function THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
 $arg1 = arg(1);
 $arg0 = arg(0);
 if($arg0 == 'models' && ($arg1 = 'model-names' || $arg1 = 'anothermodel')){
  $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__fixed';
 }
}
```